# Laravel multi-tenant SaaS - vendors with customers

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, saas

After 48 hours of research on Multi-tenant SaaS approach with Laravel, I got some idea about it.

1. Single code-base, shared DB
2. Single code-base, multiple DB
3. Multiple code-base, multiple DB

I chose to go with option 1, since the project budget is small & this is my first SaaS project.

My problem over here is with Vendors (with own domain) having their own set of customers.

I'm using `zizaco/entrust` for role management here.

So the main thing is, I'm not getting an idea of how to do it with Laravel's default AUTH middleware. Since, a customer should be able to register with different vendors. How do we manage it in `users` table of default laravel installation?

Comment: Take a look at https://multitenantlaravel.com/ and also wait a bit for videos from Laracon US 2017.

Comment: ...The link for the video mentioned above is https://streamacon.com/video/laracon-us-2017/day-1-tom-schlick

Comment: @RossWilson In that video, the 1st question bothered me, for choosing the correct strategy, "Do you commonly need to display information from multiple tenants on the same page?", can't we achieve this with Multiple DB? Because PROS of Multiple DB multi-tenancy seems promising.